# How to create minmap in like other modern code editor in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a code editor and I want to create a minimap like other code editor have but I have no idea about how to create it in python tkinter

I want to create minimap like in this image
[image]

this is what I am creating:-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text widgets can have *peers* - two or more widgets that share the same content. Just give the second text widget a tiny font.

Unfortunately, tkinter's support of peer widgets isn't complete, so it's best to create a helper class to do most of the work. I provided an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58290100/7432) to the question [How to enter text into two text widgets by just entring into same widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286794/how-to-enter-text-into-two-text-widgets-by-just-entring-into-same-widget)

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

class TextPeer(tk.Text):
    """A peer of an existing text widget"""
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, master, cnf={}, **kw):
        TextPeer.count += 1
        parent = master.master
        peerName = "peer-{}".format(TextPeer.count)
        if str(parent) == ".":
            peerPath = ".{}".format(peerName)
        else:
            peerPath = "{}.{}".format(parent, peerName)

        # Create the peer
        master.tk.call(master, 'peer', 'create', peerPath, *self._options(cnf, kw))

        # Create the tkinter widget based on the peer
        # We can't call tk.Text.__init__ because it will try to
        # create a new text widget. Instead, we want to use
        # the peer widget that has already been created.
        tk.BaseWidget._setup(self, parent, {'name': peerName})

root = tk.Tk()

text_font = Font(family="Courier", size=14)
map_font = Font(family="Courier", size=4)

text = tk.Text(root, font=text_font, background="black", foreground="white")
minimap = TextPeer(text, font=map_font, state="disabled",
                   background="black", foreground="white")

minimap.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Sir thanks for solving my problem but one problem occurs that is my undo function is not working when ever I use minimap ,Sir how to fix it please

Comment: @Coder you have not provided any information on how your undo function works.

Comment: @Billy Sir, In this have provide information related it 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72028117/undo-function-of-text-widget-isnt-working-whenever-i-attach-minimap-with-it-in